# As soon as vs. Just as or immediately after

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Today I mailed  notes to one of my classmates. Under the subject I typed " **Reply immediately after receiving**". But the thing is, I am a bit skeptical about the grammar of the sentence
 which I always am  when it comes to using English either in speaking or writing. But this time I am asking you native speakers of English.

Would you have said it differently? and my second question is can I reword the sentence in the following way:

**Replay as soon as you receive .**. Or

**Reply just as you receive.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **reply immediately** is enough, logically speaking, but you can add _on receipt, on receiving, upon receiving, upon receipt_  Also: right away, at once, straight away.

Comment: You might try: kindly reply as soon as possible

Comment: @kuldeepsharma It seems you don't know how to [accept an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Use the check mark next to accept the answer you find most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between ***as soon as*** and ***just as*** can be illustrated by comparing...

> 1: *John opened the door **as soon as** I rang the bell*
>    2: *John opened the door **just as** I rang the bell*

...where #1 means there was a ***minimal delay*** between the two events - presumably because John wasn't far from the door at the time, and he went and opened it as quickly as possible once he heard the doorbell.

But #2 means there was ***no delay***. John must have already been ***just about to*** open the door (perhaps he was going out anyway, and had no idea that someone was about to ring the bell).

---

It's *not* idiomatic to use ***just as*** in OP's context (native speakers would struggle to understand the intent, and might well end up "deciphering" it as *Reply **in the same manner** as you receive [the message]* (perhaps, *If you got this message by email, reply by email, not by a phone call*).

Comment: So can I use "as soon as"  here?

Comment: @kuldeep sharma: I suppose if you were my boss, I'd have no choice but to reply *as soon as **possible*** after receiving such an instruction - but if you had no such authority over me, and you *didn't* include that "politely softening" word ***possible***, I'd either ignore it or deliberately wait as ***long*** as possible before replying. Without even so much as a ***please***, your *Reply as soon as you receive this* would strike me as incredibly rude / peremptory.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but How can I add "possible" in the following sentence. " reply as as soon as you receive it" if I cannot so then I think I can add "please" and it wouldn't sound rude e.g. " please reply as soon as you receive it.

Comment: As @Lambie already pointed out, [You might try: **Kindly reply as soon as possible**.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/179145/as-soon-as-vs-just-as-or-immediately-after/179147?noredirect=1#comment356396_179145) But I'm not here to teach you manners - just to correct basic points concerning idiomatic / grammatical usage in English.